# nested swing containers not displaying

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent

```
//TbsgMain.java:
package tbsg;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TbsgMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  TbsgEngine engine = new TbsgEngine();
  JFrame mainFrame = new TbsgFrame(engine);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);

 }

}

//TbsgFrame.java
package tbsg;

class TbsgFrame extends JFrame {

 private TbsgEngine engine;
 private JLayeredPane mainScreen;
 private JLabel label1;

 public TbsgFrame(TbsgEngine eng) {
  engine = eng;
  setTitle("TBSG");
  setLocation(10, 10);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  mainScreen = new JLayeredPane();

  label1 = new JLabel();
  label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imgs/hex."
    + "png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(115, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
  mainScreen.add(label1, 0);
  this.add(mainScreen);
  this.pack();
 }

}
```

I'm doing an assignment, that would require multiple different swing containers and components (JPanel, JLayeredPane, JLabel, JButton, etc.) to be placed within eachother and ultimately within the JFrame called "mainFrame", but with this code, i only get an empty frame. So far the only time the image in the JLabels has appeared, was when i added it directly to the JFrame, like so:

```
    //TbsgFrame.java
package tbsg;

class TbsgFrame extends JFrame {

 private TbsgEngine engine;
 private JLabel label1;

 public TbsgFrame(TbsgEngine eng) {
  engine = eng;
  setTitle("TBSG");
  setLocation(10, 10);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  label1 = new JLabel();
  label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imgs/"
    + "hex.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(115, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
  this.add(label1);
  this.pack();
 }

}
```

How could i get the JPanel (and later other components) to appear? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Nest JComponents *does work*.  I do it all the time.  I'll take a quick look at your code, but in the meantime you do need to execute **all** [Swing code on the Event Dispatch Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)  Start with that change.

Comment: JLaywredPane doesn't have a LayoutManager by default, unless you supply one, you'll need to set the size of the components you add to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"By default, a layered pane has no layout manager." — [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Set bounds for your label and it will appear. For example:

```
label1.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 100);
```

Keep in mind that you are doing this for assignment purposes, and that in practice you probably wouldn't set component's bounds, unless you are using absolute layout on purpose.

Edit:
As MadProgrammer pointed out, you can also set the layout manager for the layered pane, in which case you needn't set the label bounds. For example:

```
mainScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer, i was worried it'd be something more complicated.